# Will SSDT publish always fail with "Data Loss May Occur" when table is rebuilt?

Tags: sql-server, ssdt, database-projects

Consider the following scenario:

- We have a SSDT database project.
- We add a new column to the middle of a table.
- This forces the database project to rebuild the table in order to deploy the change.
- We publish this SSDT database project  with the setting “Block incremental deployment if data loss might occur” enabled.
- Because we have the above setting enabled, and (also, I think) the table is being rebuilt the deployment (correctly) throws an error saying data loss may occur.

My question is this: Can we rely on the fact that whenever the table needs to be rebuilt as part of a SSDT publish this error will be thrown?

Comment: Are you adding a NOT NULL column?

Comment: No, I was adding a NULL column or a NOT NULL column with a DEFAULT.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can rely on that. When you enable the "BlockOnDataLoss" attribute what actually happens is that SSDT adds to the deployment script a check like this one

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM TableToChange)
BEGIN
     RAISEERROR ...
END
```